# Can we project only certain desktop on second screen, like how ubuntu does?

Tags: windows-10

I want to have a set up where the second screen only shows an app.
So my laptop screen will have the normal one, can move between desktop, but the second screen (monitor) only displaying a desktop regardless of my laptop screen is currently showing different desktop.

Does thas option available in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Open the app you want to appear on your external monitor, then click on the Resize button at upper right (as shown circled below).

[image: Resize button]

Drag and drop it to the external monitor's screen.

Close the app with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Reopen the app, and maximize its window.

Close the app with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Now, when the app opens, it will open maximized in the external monitor screen.

To have it launch automatically when Windows boots up, do <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `shell:startup` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Startup items in File Explorer]

In the File Explorer window which opens, paste a shortcut to the app you want to open.

The next time you boot up, the preferred app will appear, fullscreen, on the External Monitor.

Comment: Before you can do this, you need to make sure the external monitor is in "Extend" mode, not "Duplicate" mode. Use Windows-Key+P to change this setting.

Comment: Wow, I remembered my question was about setting only a desktop on the external monitor screen, not apps. why it's changed now. Obviously, with the above question this answer works.

Comment: @otong, I will restore the original question for you. My apologies for assuming I knew what you wanted.